# c# Generic type and real type associations

Tags: c#, types, metadata

I´m building a communications system using tcp/ip. I´m using .NET, C# and VS2012.

Those systems exchange metada between them. The basic message contains the metadata name and it´s value (the data itself). One system doesn´t know the other system datatypes.

The message has the following struct: FromNode, ToNode, MetadataName, MetadataType, MetadataSizeInBytes, MetadataValue. All messages are pure byte[] with delimited fields (not serialized, as some systems can be Unix flavoured).

When receiving that message I would like to associate the metadata to a real variable, based on its type. So I built the following class:

public class RealMetadata

```
{
         public string Type { get; set; }
         public Type   Value { get; set; } <<--- I´ve tried var and object, with no success.
}
```

Later on code I wanna access the real value of Metadata:

```
if (Type == "INTEGER")
      int RealValue = (int) Value;
if (Type == "STRING")
      string RealValue;
      Buffer.Blockcopy (RealValue, 0, Value, 0, MetadataSizeInValues * sizeof (char));
if (Type == "FLOAT")
      float RealValue = (float) Value;
```

This whole thing sometimes don´t compile or doesn´t work at runtime. I don´t know exactly what type Value shall be declared on the class property, and how to get its data to a real variable.

Thanks a lot for any idea or suggestion.

Rds

Answer (score 1):

You should be using an object to hold the data and a Type object to hold the type of the data stored, like bellow:

```
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public Object Value { get; set; }


        if (Type == typeof (int))
        {
            int realValue = (int) Value;
        }
        if (Type == typeof(string))
        {
            string RealValue;
            Buffer.Blockcopy(RealValue, 0, Value, 0, MetadataSizeInValues*sizeof (char));
        }
        if (Type == typeof(float))
        {
            float RealValue = (float) Value;
        }
```

Comment: Yes, I keep the type as a String, not as a type.I´ve tried Object already as has given me error at runtime when casting in (int) Value. I will do a new try.